# Этимология слова "позволить"

Tags: этимология, морфология

Как появилось слова "позволить", "позволять"? Ясно виден корень "вол", однако происхождение и значение буквосочетания "поз-" для меня совершенно непонятно.

Comment: Глагол - целиком заимствование. Основа слова - *позволи-.* См. Этимологический словарь Крылова: *Этот глагол является заимствованием из польского, где pozwolic образовано с помощью приставки от wolic, произведенного от wola – "воля".*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Большой этиологический словарь (Климова М. В.)

**ПОЗВОЛИТЬ**. Возникновение XVII век, от польского pozwolic от wola - воля.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**У Черных есть статья про "дозволить"**

**ДОЗВОЛИТЬ** - префиксальное образование к "волити", в словарях только с 1771 года, в текстах с XVI века, **ЕДВА ЛИ УКРАИНИЗМ И ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ ПОЛОНИЗМ**, весьма вероятно, что  приставка Z существовала **в праславянском языке.**

Кроме того, у Черных есть статья про приставку ИЗ  (общеславянская IZ) и ее краткий безударный вариант Z, который и присутствует в глаголах "позволить, дозволить".

**Также обратим внимание н приставку ВОЗ/ВЗ**, который, как считает Черных, также состоит из двух приставок ВО+З и В+З.

**Поэтому делаем выводы:**

1) не факт, что позволить/дозволить  польского происхождения;

2) Тихонову не стоит включать З в корень;

3) приставка З входит в состав приставок ВОЗ/ВЗ, ДОЗ, ПОЗ.

Comment: А что такое З всё-таки? Ведь такой приставки вроде нету. Это не усечённая приставка ИЗ?

Comment: Здесь, скорее всего, две приставки PO + Z,  где Z - аналог русской приставки  С. Например,  в текстах встречается слово "свольничать" , хотя в словарях его нет: "Григорьев мог быть хорошим и относительно точным переводчиком, но если в его творческих интересах было важно "свольничать", то он свободно переставлял акценты, изменял ситуацию, изменял ритм".

Comment: Тихонов относит З к корню: по/звол/ить, до/звол/ить, вы/звол/ить. Вряд ли можно считать, что во всех этих словах  З восходит именно к приставке ИЗ, а не к приставке С. Приставка С имеет значение завершенного действия (делать - сделать) и необходима  здесь для правильного понимания значения этих глаголов (сравнить: по/вол/ить - по/з/вол/ить).

Comment: Понятно, Sibylla, спасибо! А почему Вы первый раз приставки написали латиницей, интересно просто? Вроде бы в слове "изволить" должен быть тот же корень, что и в "позволить", а по Тихонову Вашему остаётся И, что тоже сложно считать приставкой.))

Comment: Да... Намудрили так намудрили!

Answer (score 2):

Артём Луговой прав: -З здесь соответствует русской приставке -ИЗ.

У Фасмера есть статья о слове ДОЗВОЛИТЬ:

Дозволить:

вероятно, из польск. dozwolić – то же ***(ввиду соответствия польского z- русскому из-)***; см. Бернекер 1, 440. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973