# Какой корень в слове "произвол"

Tags: корень-слова

Какой корень в слове "произвол"?
"Вол" или "произвол"?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424940/Этимология-слова-позволить

Comment: там же другие слова

Comment: Разные связанные с корнем приставки, но в любом случае там корень не "вол".  Видите, какой сложный исторический анализ морфем приходится делать.  Здесь ИЗ, а там З, но никто корневую основу в современном языке на части не делит.